# Sending data 5 items through a loop and receiving 7?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var ordered = {
  actions: [
    'index',    //  GET   /
    'new',      //  GET   /new
    'create',   //  POST  /
    'show',     //  GET   /:id
    'edit',     //  GET   /edit/:id
    'update',   //  PUT   /:id
    'patch',    //  PATCH /:id
    'destroy',  //  DEL   /:id
  ],
  methods: [
    'get',
    'post',
    'put',
    'patch',
    'delete'
  ]
};
```

I'm making a loop in the ordered.methods and passing to a prototype, but i'm receiving wrong in the prototype.

```
ordered.methods.forEach(function(method){
  Resource.prototype[method] = function(path, fn) {
    if ('function' == typeof path || 'object' == typeof path) {
      fn = path, path = '';
    }
    this.map(method, path, fn);
    return this;
  }
});
```

When i do a console.log in the method in the looping, the data is right, just the get, post, put, patch and delete is showing, but when i try to do a console.log in the Resource.prototype.map, this is showing in my console:

```
get
get
post
get
get
put
delete
```

How can i fix that?

Resource.prototype.map:

```
Resource.prototype.map = function(method, path, fn){
  console.log(method);

};
```

Comment: What does `Resource.prototype.map` look like?

Comment: How do you call the `Resource.prototype[method]` methods that you're creating in the loop?

Comment: Nothing is getting executed inside the loop , you're just assigning values. the console messages is coming from other parts of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should be the expected behavior, because the `this.map(method, path, fn)` is not called inside the `ordered.methods.forEach`, but it is called in the `Resource.get` / `Resource.post` / `Resource.put` etc.